# Android phonegap app questions

Tags: android, cordova

I'm starting to get into turing an iPad app I made with phonegap and converting it to become an android app as well. But where as Xcode lets you specify iPad only, I'm not seeing this option any where in the new Android Studio IDE. Is this an option when working with Android? Any ideas or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode would not give you an option to convert your iOS app for Android. If you are going the native way, then you use XCode for the iOS app and Eclipse for the Android app. If you want to save time and effort, then framework like PhoneGap is created for this very purpose. Instead of using Objective C or Java, you create the app with HTML, JS and CSS and it would work on all major supported platforms of PhoneGap.

About the form factor/screen size, Eclipse does not filter on screen size, however the Play Store does and this is controlled by the [supports-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) manifest attribute.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I thought it got added to my tags but I guess it didn't but the base of my app is phonegap. 

Alright, I thought that you had the option to set what kind of device the app could run on as you do in Xcode. Thanks for the link to the article.